# Converting JSON from REST API to Unicode problem in Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, utf-8, rest

So I'm getting JSON data from WordPress's REST API in Dart with this code:

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; 
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    Future<List> fetchWpPosts() async {
   var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
   final response = await http
          .get(url, headers: {'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-16'});
   var convertDatatoJson = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
   return convertDatatoJson; }
```

And this code is doing the job, except some characters still show as Unicode. On the website they show as they should.

Here's a [pic of the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAr6e.jpg)

And here is the JSON code that I target:

```
"title": {
  "rendered":
 "АСДФГХЙКЛЖ&#8221;ШЩ>?Ч!@№$%€§*()_&#8212;&#8212;&#8220;ENG&#8221;________асд&#8221;асд&#8221;"
},
```

JSON obviously encode only some characters in unicode - that is only some " and ', onters " and ' show as they should.
Then my code gets them and shows them as they are without convert them to utf-8.

Can I fix this in Dart or I have to do something to the wordpress site?

Thank you!

Comment: is your server sends `&#8212` as ascii you will get the same ascii on the client side - most likely you need to encode them on the server side

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, yes...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem like that

````
var response = await http.get(url).timeout(const Duration(minutes: 3));
      const utf8Decoder = Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true);
      final decodedBytes = utf8Decoder.convert(response.bodyBytes);
    ```
````